# Using regex, I want to be able to get each match and replace it with something specific

Tags: jquery, regex, string, replace, substring

If I have the following string:

> The dog, the cat and the Catterpillar.

And a regex that matches 'cat' (upper or lower case), there would be two matches in '*cat*' and '*cat*terpillar'. So far so good, but I want to replace those under the condition if the match has a space or not right after. The first 'cat' would be replaced by X and the 'cat' in 'catterpillar' would be replaced by Y, for example.

Is there a way to acoomplish this using jQuery? Replace matches conditionally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = "The dog, the cat and the Catterpillar."
str.replace(/cat /gi, "X ");
str.replace(/cat/gi, "Y");
```

Comment: Mmmh, I believe the idea of the question is not to capture the space, but to check for its existence.

Comment: @mrks i think the idea is to replace the existence, and my code is fairly self explanatory and easy to use.

Comment: add i after g ( str.replace(/cat /gi, "X " )  because he asked for ignore case ;)

Comment: This should work, but if I have a slightly more complicated logic, like 10 or more cases for replacing, this would make the code a little too poluted, don't you think?

Comment: @RenatoOliveira , well i gave the answer considering the complexity you have mentioned in the OP. If you have a more complex problem then you should mention it in OP. I simply can't assume it. I gave you the answer keeping in mind the tradeoff of complexity and elegance.

Comment: Nevermind, I think your solution will work great. I'm testing it already, and it works as expected. The rest of the logic I can handle on my own. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use boundaries:

```
/\bcat\b/i
'The dog, the cat and the Catterpillar.'.replace(/\bcat\b/i, 'horse')
```

Alternatively, if you really only want the space as a delimiter, you can use positive lookaheads:

```
/cat(?= )/i
'The dog, the cat and the Catterpillar.'.replace(/cat(?= )/i, 'horse')
```

Answer (score 0):

> [**str.replace**( `regexp`|`substr`, `newSubStr`|`function` `[, flags]`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
>
> The **`replace()`** method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement. The pattern can be a string or a RegExp, and the replacement can be a string or a **function** to be called for each match.

We can use an optional [group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):

```
/cat( )?/gi
```

And using a function to evaluate if the group is set:

```js
var str = "The dog, the cat and the Catterpillar."

var result = str.replace(/cat( )?/gi, function (match,space) {
    if (typeof space === "undefined") {
        return 'Y';
    } else {
        return 'X' + space;
    }
});

document.body.innerText += result;
```